# Low battery cut-off circuit 40 V

Tags: mosfet, batteries

I am trying to create my first circuit for a battery-powered speaker. The battery which I use is a 40 V powertool battery. Now I want to build a circuit to protect the battery from deep discharge.

I found a [paper](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/battery-protection-circuit.html) on analog.com with a cut-off circuit for a single lithium-ion cell. Now I tried to change the circuit for my specific project, but since I am not really into electric circuits I have some questions about the circuit which I built.

1. Is there a way to power the LT1495 with the 40 V from my battery or do I have to choose another op-amp since the operating voltage is 36 V?
2. Will the PMOS in my circuit work? I had a look in the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/1/FDD4141_D-1806816.pdf): max U_ds = 40 V and I_d = 50 A and in continuous mode 10.8 A.
3. I am not sure how to calculate the resistors R3 and R4 for the hysteresis of my battery.

The specifications are:

- At maximal power the speaker amplifier can draw 10 A.
- The cut-off voltage should be 36 V
- Low energy consumption
  [image]

Edit:

Here is the output of my Simulation:

[image]

For me, it looks like the circuit is switching at the right voltage.

I hope everything is clear and I didn't make huge mistakes.

Edit 2.1:

I have now changed the things mentioned in the comments. I have added two capacitors of 100n. I also added a Zener diode (BZX84C8V2LT1G) to limit the source-gate voltage. There are no traces under a SOIC sticker. Finally, the GND traces are now the same size as the V+ trace, so they can carry the same current as V+.

Are there any bugs that I still need to adjust?

[image: New PCB-Layout with changes]
[image: Circuit with changes]

Comment: You need to connect the other two source pins of Q1 to get the high current capacity. You do not show the connections to the four drain pins on the schematic. And on U1, connect pin 6 to pin 7, and pin 5 to GND. Op-amp unused pins should not be left floating. You also need a bypass capacitor of around 100 nF on the op-amp supply rails, and perhaps another across R3 as a filter.

Comment: You also need to put a resistor of about 20k from Q1 gate to source, to limit gate voltage to about 8 volts. Or maybe a zener of 6 to 10 volts.

Comment: This isn't what you're asking about, but that layout for the MOSFET is abysmal. It looks like you're intentionally trying to use only one pin for the source and going out of your way to use *only* the exposed pad for the drain. You should use all three source pins and all four drain pins (plus exposed pad) if you want to use the part at its rated current.

Comment: You've also made all your ground traces *tiny*; if you wire this module to the outside world in the obvious way, the ground traces on your PCB will be carrying the same current as the thick high-current traces. But they'll have much higher resistance due to being about a tenth the width.

Comment: There are many issues with that layout. The ground net traces should be much wider, especially if they will be used as a return for the 10 amp current for the speaker. And don't run tracks between pads of an SOIC decal unless absolutely unavoidable, which does not apply here.

Comment: At first, thank you very much for a help. I have some questions to your comments. The resistor of 20k to limit gate voltage, is this one not too small? I have simulated my circuit with the resistor between gate and source but i have still higher voltage than 8V.  Can i set complete second layer of my PCB to ground and connect all related pins to this layer or is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show the results of your simulation to determine if the circuit will switch at the desired high and low setpoints. It looks like your choice of 1 Meg and 100k for R5 and R6 will result in a nominal operating voltage of 11 * 1.25V or 13.75V. You will have to work out the values of R2 and R4 for the hysteresis. And you need to use an op-amp rated at least 44V, like the LT1078 or LT1636.

Here is a full simulation of your circuit. Note that the hysteresis is excessive, and although it switches on at the desired voltage, it does not switch off until about 12 volts. Also, your MOSFET is only rated at 30 volts.

[image: Low Battery Cutoff]

Here is a circuit using a 44V op-amp LT1638 and an 80V MOSFET. I used a different form of hysteresis, which I think is better.

[image: Low Battery Cutoff]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have edited my post. I will try to simulate the circuit with the other op-amp.

Comment: I would change R5 to a much lower value, and add a zener from source to gate to limit it to about 15V. The MOSFET will not draw current through the gate unless it is being changed.  If it were my design I would power everything downstream from the MOSFET with a reset button that would turn the MOSFET on to power everything. If the battery is low it will shut down. This eliminates the parasitic drain when off.

Comment: I have added a Zener from source to gate, which limits the voltage to about 8V. Why would you change R5 to a much lower value? Are there any benefits to this?